# Using Context inside a Class Instance in React.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm trying to use [template design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method), to refactor a complex business logic in my React application. I have 3-4 flows where-in some steps are common, but have slightly different implementations or addition and intermediate steps.

For this I'm creating an abstract base class in TypeScript with concrete implementation of few steps. The Classes that will extend this abstract class needs to provide concrete implementation of the abstract methods defined inside base class.

Now, the problem/query I'm having is regarding using Context API and Hooks(like useHistory) inside these Plain TypeScript classes (that are not extending `React.Component`).

The code looks something like:

```js
import { MyContext } from './common/utils/MyContext';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const context = React.useContext(MyContext);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (foo && bar) {
      const flowInitializer1 = new flowInitializer1(history, context, foo, bar);
      flowInitializer1.initiate();
    } else if (foo && bazz) {
      const flowInitializer2 = new flowInitializer2(history, context, foo, bazz);
      flowInitializer2.initiate();
    } else {
      const flowInitializer3 = new flowInitializer3(history, context);
      flowInitializer3.initiate();
      flowInitializer3.cleanup();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    // some JSX
  );
}

abstract class BaseFlowInitializer {
    constructor(
      context: IContextType,
      history:  RouteComponentProps['history']
    ) {}

    step1() {
      this.context.foo();
      // some code 
    }

    step2() {
      // some code
      history.push('/fizzbuz');
    }

    abstract step3();

    abstract initiate();
}

export class flowInitializer1 extends BaseFlowInitializer {
  step3() {
    // concrete implementation
  }

  initiate() {
    // concrete implementation
  }
}

export class flowInitializer2 extends BaseFlowInitializer {
  step3() {
    // concrete implementation
  }

  step4() {

  }

  initiate() {
    // concrete implementation
  }
}

export class flowInitializer3 extends BaseFlowInitializer {
  step3() {
    // concrete implementation
  }

  cleanup() {
    // some additional step
  }

  initiate() {
    // concrete implementation
  }
}
```

My Questions now are:

1. Is the above implementation recommended as per React standards?
2. Can the above code cause performance issues, by breaking the React Fibre?
3. Is there any better way to implement template design pattern in React.js?